# What is the use of [,]?

Tags: c#

```
string[,] table;
```

Will this really create a table for the console application in C# or is there an alternative way of creating a real table other than putting individual characters?

Comment: That is a double dimensional array of strings, which you can also view as a table.

Comment: This is a multidimensional array: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/2yd9wwz4(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I suggest reading a c# tutorial. The code you presented will declare a 2 dimensional array of strings. it's very basic c#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> string[,] table;
> ```

Declares (as comments have noted) a [two-dimensional array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx). Thus:

```
table = new string[2,2];
table[0, 0] = "Top left";
table[0, 1] = "Bottom left";
table[1, 0] = "Top right";
table[1, 1] = "Bottom right":
```

(Using the obvious orientation.)

Compare:

```
// Three dimensional:
var table3 = new string[2,2,2];

// Array of arrays
string[][] tt = new string[2][];
tt[0] = new string[2];
tt[1] = new string[3]; // Second row is longer!
tt[0][0] = "Top left";
tt[0][1] = "Top right";
tt[1][0] = "Bottom left";
tt[1][1] = "Bottom right";
tt[1][2] = "Bottom extra right";
```

These are also known as [Jagged Arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/2s05feca.aspx).

***EDIT*** Fuller demonstration of the latter case (which are generally more useful), including two ways to enumeration.

- Nested loops are easy to understand, but you always need to (implicitly) have those nested loops.
- Flattening into a single dimensional structure which allows a lot more power (because there is generally a lot more support for single dimensional structures across BCL and other libraries)

Of course using `SelectMany` is a steeper learning curve and is overkill for this simple case:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine("Array of arrays");
        string[][] tt = new string[2][];
        tt[0] = new string[2];
        tt[1] = new string[3]; // Second row is longer!
        tt[0][0] = "Top left";
        tt[0][1] = "Top right";
        tt[1][0] = "Bottom left";
        tt[1][1] = "Bottom right";
        tt[1][2] = "Bottom extra right";

        NestedLoops(tt);
        Flatten(tt);
    }

    private static void NestedLoops(string[][] tt) {
        Console.WriteLine("  Nested:");
        for (int outerIdx = 0; outerIdx < tt.Length; ++outerIdx) {
            var inner = tt[outerIdx];
            for (int innerIdx = 0; innerIdx < inner.Length; ++innerIdx) {
                Console.WriteLine("    [{0}, {1}] = " + inner[innerIdx], outerIdx, innerIdx);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Flatten(IEnumerable<string[]> tt) {
        Console.WriteLine("  Falattened:");
        var values = tt.SelectMany((innerArray, outerIdx)
                                => innerArray.Select((string val, int innerIdx)
                                    => new { OuterIndex = outerIdx, InnerIndex = innerIdx, Value = val }));
        foreach (var val in values) {
            Console.WriteLine("    [{0}, {1}] = " + val.Value, val.OuterIndex, val.InnerIndex);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: how can i display the two dimensional arrays?

Comment: @milkway Either nested loops (easy) or `SelectMany` from LINQ to flatten (conceptually harder but very powerful).

Answer (score 0):

As said above, that's a two-dimensional string array. You can see it as a table for sure.

There is also a two-dimensional jagged array which is an array with different lengths. And there is also bigger multi-dimensional arrays as well.

But for your "table", if you got values in the array, you can use `for-loop` to get the values out from it. In your case, you need a `nested for-loop` to get the values added in, for example, a list box.